# CodeIgniter 3 html helper ul function, how to pass parameters to li's

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, zurb-foundation

I am implementing a site with CodeIgniter 3 and I am using the [HTML helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/html_helper.html) which works fine for what I need. I have the following arrays for my UL

```
$links = array(
    anchor(index_page(),"Home",(uri_string() == "" ? array('class' => 'active') : '')),
    anchor("about-us","About Us",(uri_string() == "about-us" ? array('class' => 'active') : '')),
    anchor("customers","Customers",(uri_string() == "customers" ? array('class' => 'active') : '')),
    anchor("policy","Policy",(uri_string() == "policy" ? array('class' => 'active') : '')),
    anchor("contact","Contact",(uri_string() == "contact" ? array('class' => 'active') : ''))
);

$attributes_normal = array(
    'id'    => 'main_menu'
);
```

So, after having those arrays I initialize my ul like this:

```
<?php echo ul($links, $attributes_normal); ?>
```

The result is as follows (about us section open for the example):

```
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li><a href="http://mysitesurl/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mysitesurl/about-us" class="active">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mysitesurl/customers">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mysitesurl/policy">Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mysitesurl/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The only question I have here, is there any way to pass the active link condition to the `<li>` element. I am using Zurb Foundation 5 and by default it adds the `class="active"` to the `<li>` element, so I want to use the default CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without overriding the default `_list` helper function. On [line 145](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.0/system/helpers/html_helper.php#L145) in the source code for HTML Helper you can see that '<li>' is hardcoded and does not accept additional arguments:

```
$out .= str_repeat(' ', $depth + 2).'<li>';
```

I would probably just set the active class using jQuery or JavaScript, but you could also opt to override the default helper functions for generating lists (see [Extending Helpers](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html#extending-helpers)).

Comment: I see, I think it would be easier to just avoid the `ul` function in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must create MY_html_helper.php into the application/helpers path

```
if ( ! function_exists('_list'))
{
/**
 * Generates the list
 *
 * Generates an HTML ordered list from an single or multi-dimensional array.
 *
 * @param   string
 * @param   mixed
 * @param   mixed
 * @param   int
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function _list($type = 'ul', $list = array(), $attributes = '', $depth = 0, $outer = '__outer', $inner = '__inner' )
{
    // If an array wasn't submitted there's nothing to do...
    if ( ! is_array($list))
    {
        return $list;
    }

    // Set the indentation based on the depth
    $out = str_repeat(' ', $depth)
        // Write the opening list tag
        .'<'.$type._stringify_attributes($attributes).">\n";


    // Cycle through the list elements.  If an array is
    // encountered we will recursively call _list()

    static $_last_list_item = '';
    foreach ($list as $key => $val)
    {
        $_last_list_item = $key;

        if ( $key !== $outer && $key !== $inner) {
            $out .= str_repeat(' ', $depth + 2) . '<li ' . (is_array($val) && array_key_exists($outer, $val) ? _stringify_attributes($val[$outer]) : '') . '>';
            if (!is_array($val)) {
                $out .= $val;
            } else {
                $out .= $_last_list_item . "\n" . _list($type, $val, (array_key_exists($inner, $val) ? $val[$inner] : ''), $depth + 4) . str_repeat(' ', $depth + 2);
            }
            $out .= "</li>\n";
        }

    }

    // Set the indentation for the closing tag and apply it
    return $out.str_repeat(' ', $depth).'</'.$type.">\n";
}
}
```

Now you can use the netx configuration for ul() function

```
$links = array(
    'Access Control' => array(
         'Users' => array(
               '__outer' => array(
                    //Here you have the config for 'User' option 'li'
                    'class' => 'active some-class',
                    'id' => 'my-unique-id'
               )
          ),
          'Roles',
          'Permissions',
          '__inner' => array(
               //Here you have the config for inner ul (sub-menu)
               'class' => 'sub-menu'
          ),
          '__outer' => array(
               //Here you have the config for 'Access Control' option 'li'
               'class' => 'active'
          ),
    ), 
);
```

__inner and __outer options don't appear into the list